# Trying to center an unordered list

Tags: html, css

On my website, I want a horizontal menu, which is centered on the page. So, the whole menu should be centred.

At this moment, I can create a horizontal list, but the list still stays at the left side. I want it centered.

Can someone please tell me what to change in my code to center it?

My HTML:

```
<div class=menu>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.menu{
    display: table;
}

div.menu a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60px;
    color: navy;
    background-color: #FF0000
}

li{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Does it work? If not, why not? What are you getting, and what is the expected result? I have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: try this: .menu ul {display:table; margin: 0 auto;}

Comment: Yup, sorry. Edited my question to be more clear

Comment: @shadeed9 this changes exactly nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `margin:auto` to your `div.menu` to accomplish this

```
div.menu{
    display: table;
    margin:auto;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0xb7j9zc/

Comment: This worked, thanks! Never thought that the answer would be this simple

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ByShine/33sz6nrt/4/

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you wish to center the menu (align it to the middle of the page). One approach, and I'm sure there's a few out there, is to wrap the 'menu' div into another `div` tag and set the `align` attribute to `center`, like so:

```
<div align="center">
    <div class=menu>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/q9ae01qe/

Comment: I wouldn't use `align="center"` but instead `margin:auto:` or `margin:0 auto`  however yours does work :)